# Mr K has a rectangular land of size m*n. What is the perimeter of largest rectangular fence?

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, implementation

**Problem:** 
Mr K has a rectangular land of size m*n. There are marshes in the land where the fence cannot hold. Mr K wants you to find the perimeter of the largest rectangular fence that can be built on this land.

**My approach:**
 It can be solved by considering pair of points as upper-left and lower-right to determine if a rectangular fence is possible in that rectangle but it would take **O(N^4) time**.

**Any suggestions for optimisation?**

Comment: This seems to be discussed at length [here](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/mr-k-marsh/forum).

Comment: @sds yup very lengthy and series of mixed opinions!!